# How do we color a plot based on a given function?

Tags: plotting, color

I'll explain the problem I have with a shorter example, since I'm working with a huge messy function. Suppose we have a real-function $f(t)$, and a curve $C(t) \in \mathbb R^3$. Now, I can use ParametricPlot3d to plot $C(t)$. My question is the following:

How do I color the curve $C(t)$ using the magnitude of $f(t)$ at each point, $P(x(t),y(t),z(t)) \in C(t)$.

I tried tinkering with ColorFunction for this, but was unsuccessful. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example. I am making up `f[t]`

```
f[t_] := Cos[t]
```

I also make `C[t]`

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[t], Cos[t], t/10}, {t, 0, 20},
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, t}, Hue[f[t]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that the Hue[f[t]] assigns the colors in this case such that the lower magnitudes are red and the higher ones are blue ?

Comment: @Lelouch:  Just look up the documentation on `Hue`.